# Exit full screen terminal

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gnome-terminal

Accidently, I entered full-screen display in the terminal. I now can't get out of the full screen display back to normal display.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Press the key <kbd>F11</kbd>. This is the typical full screen button for most ubuntu programs, like image viewer and Firefox / Google Chrome.

---

You may have (but this is unlikely) accessed `tty`. If the above doesn't work, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Comment: tty didn't work for me on uBuntu 14.04 LTS but CTRL+ALT+F7 did.

Comment: @AlainD What I meant was, you have gone into something called `tty`.

Comment: I just made the window occupy all of the screen space by dragging it into the top... oops. In case there's anyone else like me

Comment: It's Ctrl+Alt+F1 these days in Ubuntu.

Comment: @JohnLittle oh GUI is in tty1 now? I do remember from my Ubuntu GNOME days it often ended up in tty2. Is there any documentation on it being tty1?

Comment: @Tim - from the [17.10 release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_Desktop): "The login screen now uses virtual terminal 1 instead of virtual terminal 7. "

Answer (score 9):

Here is another way, in case @Tim's answer doesn't work for some reason. Right click in the terminal, then click "Leave full screen".

Answer (score 3):

None of the above worked for me.
Try pressing the <kbd>right control key</kbd> and the letter <kbd>c</kbd>:

<kbd>right ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: This worked for me when no other suggestions worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Alt-F11 worked for me in Debian Buster.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In **Ubuntu 20.04**, to toggle full-screen mode in terminal, type `Super` + `F11`